# Replacing a specific combination in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I have the following list:

```
l={{a},{a,b},{a,d},{b,d},{a,b,c},{a,d,b}}
```

I want to replace a,b with x such that I get:

```
{{a},{x},{a,d},{b,d},{x,c},{x,d}}
```

So where every there is a,b in elements of the list I need to to be replaced by letter x, I tried Replace and ReplacePart but I can not figure it out.

Comment: Since the last element transforms like `{a,d,b} -> {x,d}`, does that mean that the order doesn't matter at all in the sublists? For instance, should `{a,a,a,d,b,b,b}` become `{x,x,x,d}`?

Comment: Order does not matter and yes it can be like {x,x,x,d}. My point is that let us suppose we do not want to use Sort. How the list can be scanned and where ever there is a,b we change it to x.

Comment: By "order does not matter," I presume `{b, a}` would also become `{x}`?

Comment: That's right :)

Comment: What about `{a, a, b, d}`? do you want  `{a, d, x}` or `{d, x}` ?

Comment: @rhermans in my case I did not need to worry about such cases as each letter takes one place at each element. But that would be another question I guess.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`OrderlessPatternSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OrderlessPatternSequence.html) would work:

```
l //. {OrderlessPatternSequence[a, b, p___]} :> {x, p}
```

If it is guaranteed that `a` and `b` occur at most once per element, then [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) is sufficient (instead of [`ReplaceRepeated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html)):

```
l /. {OrderlessPatternSequence[a, b, p___]} :> {x, p}
```

Comment: it seems  you don't need `ReplaceRepeated`  (`ReplaceAll` will do). (+1)

Comment: @kglr without `ReplaceRepeated`, `{a, a, b, b}` would become `{x, a, b}`, which I inferred isn't desirable (from the second comment under OP).

Comment: ah, i see. Thanks.

Comment: @kglr edited answer to reflect that.

Comment: If performance is important consider using `Replace` at *levelspec* `{1}`.

Answer (score 6):

Something like

```
l //. {pre___, a, mid___, b, post___} | {pre___, b, mid___, a, post___}  :> {pre, x, mid, post}
```

should work.

Answer (score 5):

For the case with no repeated elements you can also use  `SequenceReplace` in combination with `OrderlessPatternSequence`:

```
SequenceReplace[{OrderlessPatternSequence[a, p___, b]} -> Sequence[x, p]] /@ l
```

> {{a}, {x}, {a, d}, {b, d}, {x, c}, {x, d}}

Answer (score 4):

Given that it's not clear what is wanted for repeated instances, *i.e.* if for `{a, a, b, d}` you want `{a, d, x}` or `{d, x}`, I offer another kind solution, that works in the second. If there are no repetitions the result is the same, but a bit slower.

```
repl = If[
   SubsetQ[#, {a, b}]
   , Prepend[Complement[#, {a, b}], x]
   , #] &;

repl /@ l
(* {{a}, {x}, {a, d}, {b, d}, {x, c}, {x, d}} *)
```